# Change directory for uploading file in FTP

Tags: java, ftp

I need to change the working directory in a Java program where i want to upload a file, but i am not able to change the working directory.
Currently i am using following code please have a look what is going wrong here.

```
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class FileUploadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            client.connect("36.109.60.40");
            client.login("XYZ", "SYSTEM");

            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            boolean changeWorkingDirectory = client.changeWorkingDirectory("ABC\\QSRC");

            if (changeWorkingDirectory)//this is false here
            {

              String filename = "ATR.CBL";

              fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\RATSYA\\Desktop\\backup\\DINAKE\\ATR.CBL");
              boolean storeFile = client.storeFile(filename, fis);
              if(storeFile)
                 System.out.println("file stored");
              else
                 System.out.println("file can not be stored");

              client.logout();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error message? Also, shouldn't you be using forward slash?

Comment: @Sudhanshu i am using function that return false, so i assume it is not able to change the directory though the directory exist there so it overrule the reason that the directory is not exist.

Comment: Please try with forward slash.

Comment: @sudhansu yes it works i am getting now it is true but as i am getting reply code 226 and store file true then still my file is getting uploaded..what could be the reason.

Comment: @Sudhanshu How could i specify here the source type of file for example i have to upload cobol file. ya i know it will store file in ascii form so wher we can store its source type and how.

Answer (score 0):

Tried "ABC/QSRC" ?

Never used it but some general ideas:

- ABC\QSRC exists in ftp directory of user XYZ?
- Did you try same login and operation with other client and it works?
- maybe you mean /ABC/QSRC

Answer (score 0):

I think I see how you can make this work. you should probably store your directory in a `String` like so: `String dir = "/Server/FTP/OtherDir/";` and than whenever you want to change directory you change that value. You can use the `String` storing the directory when you want to upload/download a file by doing something like this:

```
dir ="/Server/FTP/OtherDir/";
yourFileWriter.write(dir + file);
```

I hope this helps!